# C# selenium target machine actively refused it only when I try to start it programmatically

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid

I need to have my selenium standalone sever start from my code but I keep getting the "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused" error. The server is started from a bat file and when I try to run the bat file programmatically I get the error. If I just click an the bat file manually it work no problem its only when I try to do it through my code that I get this error.

The sever version is 4.4.0

```
[BeforeTestRun]
public static void setUp()
{
   StreamWriter sw =new StreamWriter("file.bat");
   sw.WriteLine("java -jar selenium-server-4.4.0.jar standalone");
   sw.Dispose();
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("file.bat");
}
```

Comment: Check Task Manger to see if app is running.  Are you an admin?  If running inside VS you do not have ADMIN unless you start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As admin.  The double click on executable outside VS will also work.

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide answer. Can you please [edit] your question to include a [repro], and more information about how you are starting the server?

Comment: @jdweng tried running VS in admin didn't work, I need to have it execute from VS unfortunately

Comment: @GregBurghardt added the code that caused the crash there is other code but this is the first bit of code and it never makes it passed this

Comment: Do you know what port the selenium server is running on? Maybe something is already running on that port? Maybe anti-virus or firewall software is blocking this?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using the Java selenium server rather than the Selenium NuGet package (which comes with its own server)?

Comment: @GregBurghardt There is nothing else running on that port, I am able to start the selenium server by manually clicking on a bat file with the same command it's only when I try to run it with the code shown above that I get my error. The only reason I am using the Java selenium server is because is how I learned to use it initially.

Comment: The Process class has no PATH defined so you need to put full path when inside Net application.   Also you need to use parameters in the process.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng the process starts, it can find the file the problem is that "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused". I executed the bat file other ways previously with a full file locution and got the same error.

Comment: The bat file must be using an Environmental variable (like Path or other).  Environment Variables are not defined when using the Process Class.  Are any other files are required to be in same folder and the bat file?  They would also need to be in same folder as the Net executable file (when in VS in the Bin folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of what jdweng said I copied the jar into the net48 and wrote this

```
 ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
 Process process;

 processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K java -jar selenium-server-4.4.0.jar standalone");
 processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

 process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: Are you posting this because it is something you tried, or did this actually solve your problem? It is a little unclear in your answer.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear it solved the issue.